# Select all unique pairs for given element - Criteria API

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, criteria

I have a 'meeting' entity with params: meetingId, catId, dogId. 
There can be a lot of meetings where pairs catId and dogId are the same.
I need to calculate how many dogs a given cat has met. In other words, I need to calculate the number of meetings of the given cat where each meeting was with a different dog.

How can I achieve this using `springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria`?

```
public long countUniqueByCatId(String catId) {
            Query query = new Query()
                    .addCriteria(Criteria.where(CAT_ID).is(catId))
                    ....
            return template.count(query, Meeting.class);
```

And the same question applies to stream.

```
meetingsList.entrySet()
                    .stream()
                    .map { it -> it.value }
                    .filter { m -> (m.getCatId() == catId) }
                    ...
                    .count();
```

Comment: Please post the `Meeting.java` code _and_ the input document sample.. There are two different questions in your post - (1) Spring Data MongoDB query, and (2) Java 8 Streams API usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code

```
CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Long> query = cb.createQuery(Long.class);
Root<meeting> meetings = query.from(meeting.class);

//here you can change meetings to your new catdogIds class 
cq.select(cb.countDistinct(meetings)).where(Criteria.where(CAT_ID).is(catId));
return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getSingleResult();
```

For the stream, you can use .distinct() but you should implement the equals method
like in this example 
https://www.journaldev.com/31860/java-stream-distinct-function

also you can create a class contains catId and dogId and then convert the result list to a set after overriding the equals method to return true when the compared object has the same cat and dog id.